# Want to define list of macros with same prefix

Tags: c++11

I have a bunch of macros to define with same prefix and I don't want to define them one by one.

Say, I want to define like:

```cpp
static constexpr str_1 = "str_1";
static constexpr str_2 = "str_2";
....
static constexpr str_100 = "str_100";
```

I tried:

```cpp
#define DECLARE_STR(variable_prefix, val_prefix, cur, max) do { \
if ((cur) < (max)) { \
    static constexpr variable_prefix##cur = val_prefix#cur; \
    DECLARE_STR(variable_prefix, val_prefix, cur+1 , max) \
} while(0)
```

But got errors: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers

Do I have a correct way to implement this?

Comment: Are you aware of vectors?

Comment: Also, please consider whether you might be describing an XY-problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Hi, you can emphasize error message use " > " symbol.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code.

First, the `do`/`while(0)` construct is useful to ensure that macros expand to a single statement. What you want to generate are variable definitions at the global namespace, for which statements are unsuited: just remove the `do`/`while(0)`. The `if` won't be able to do anything about declaring variables either, it can only branch at runtime on values. But in any case...

The other issue is that you're trying to call the macro recursively. The C++ preprocessor is not able to perform such recursion: a macro cannot be expanded within its own expansion. Working around that requires a lot of boilerplate to generate iteration sequences up to a limit. Fortunately(?), Boost.Preprocessor has the boilerplate already done:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repeat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/elem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>

#define DECLARE_ONE_STR(z, n, data) \
    static constexpr BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0, data), n) = BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(1, data) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(n);

#define DECLARE_STR(variable_prefix, val_prefix, max) \
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(max, DECLARE_ONE_STR, (variable_prefix, val_prefix))
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a848c4fff8d08628)